# I have lots of Jupyter notebooks in the Home Page which is shown when Jupyter starts up. How do I clean some of them?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have lots of Jupyter notebooks in the Home Page which is shown when Jupyter starts up. How do I clean some of them? Example lets say I want the top 7 notebooks to NOT be shown when I start Jupyter (thus avoiding clutter) without deleting them

[image: screnshot of home screen for jupyter]

Comment: Perhaps move them into a folder?

Answer (score 1):

It's only the folder structure from where your `jupyter-notebooks` runs. `Move` or `delete`   or 'keep in a separate directory', the files from that location you don't want to see on its start page.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted them in the home window of Jupyter. It didn't delete the notebooks in the file system. It cleaned up my home window in Jupyter. When I needed a notebook I just uploaded it again.

There was no need to move the notebooks